error permisos en mysql
requiero otorgar permisos en MySQL a un usuario, pero me da el siguiente error, adjunto lo que intente en query:
**CREATE USER 'usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña ';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON base de datos. * TO 'usuario'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; **





FLUSH PRIVILEGES    Error Code: 1030. Got error 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" from storage engine Aria    0.000 sec


No sé si estás desde PHPMyAdmin o desde consola. Si es el primer caso, tal vez los comentarios de esta pregunta te ayuden (no me guío por la respuesta porque en varios sitios respondieron lo mismo que se menciona en un comentario de tal pregunta). Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

desde  workbench, ejecute el query.

Te dice que hay tablas corruptas en el schema mysql. Mira esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864367/1030-got-error-176-read-page-with-wrong-checksum-from-storage-engine-aria
